# wordpress child theme with WooCommerce, cant change the shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing a WordPress theme, I install the WooCommerce plugin to the site.

I created a child theme and activated then copied the `woocommerce` folder to child theme from plugin folder.

```
/wp-content/themes/west-child/woocommerce/
```

But web when I customize the child theme, `woocommerce` folder files it didn't effect. I want to customize the shop page.

Comment: in woocoommerce folder where you putted the files

Comment: what is the hierarchy you followed

Answer (score 1):

All the Template files can be found within the `/woocommerce/templates/` directory:

For example if you want to override the `archive-product.php` in 
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`

Paste it directly in woocommerce folder that is `wp-content/themes/west-child/woocommerce/archive-product.php` remove the template folder

Comment: I did as you said. but the product page is not updated. 
( i copy the wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php) and paste it in the wp-content/themes/west-child/woocommerce/archive-product.php . I add some text. but its not working. 
are you sure about  wp-content/themes/west-child/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php or maybe type mistake